# when running lit-localize - getting error - TS2324: Expected at least 2 arguments to msg(), got 1 on all uses of msg('some text')

Tags: typescript, lit-element, lit

I get - error TS2324: Expected at least 2 arguments to msg(), got 1

- for all uses of msg.

Not sure what we have done wrong tried to run the example project also but it doesn't build FYI

- [Lit] - version: "2.8.0"
- [@lit/localize] version: "0.12.1"
- [@lit/localize-tools] - version : "^0.7.2"
- [typescript] - version: "^5.3.3"

1. Wraps a few string values in msg
2. set up lit-localize.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lit/lit/main/packages/localize-tools/config.schema.json",
  "sourceLocale": "en",
  "targetLocales": ["es-419", "zh-Hans", "zh_CN"],
  "tsConfig": "tsconfig.json",
  "output": {
    "mode": "runtime",
    "outputDir": "src/i18n/generated/locales",
    "localeCodesModule": "src/i18n/generated/locale-codes.ts"
  },
  "interchange": {
    "format": "xliff",
    "xliffDir": "./xliff/"
  }
}
```

3. run 'npx lit-localize' command
4. I get - error TS2324: Expected at least 2 arguments to msg(), got 1

- for all uses of msg.